# What are the different Lucene Syntaxes called?

Tags: syntax, lucene

There are two ways of formulating a Lucene query:

> "jakarta apache" AND "Apache Lucene"

and

> +"jakarta apache" +"Apache Lucene"

Do they have names? What are they called?

---

The reason I ask ("what I actually need"):

- I have a sizeable corpus of Lucene queries in syntax number 1, and would like to re-phrase them to syntax number 2, because...
- ... I'm planning on re-using them with a [Bleve](http://www.blevesearch.com/) index, which afaik only supports syntax number 2.
- I tried to find a tool that would do the re-phrasing automatically, but have no idea what to google for. :-/

Comment: If your queries are relatively simple, you might be able to get away with: `queryParser.parse(queryString).toString(defaultFieldName)`. I don't believe `Query.toString()` ever uses AND/OR/NOT syntax.

Comment: @femtoRgon Thank you, that helps!